# The Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

**Theorem** $S^{n-1}$ disconnects $S^n$ into two open connected components, which have $S^{n-1}$ as frontier.

> In $R^3$, if we replace sphere of standard torus with genus $g\geq1$, we may have "The Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem" intuitively. Then what happens when we replace topological sphere of topology torus with genus $g\geq1$?
>
> We have $T^n$ in $R^{n+1}$, so do we have the same theorem?
>
> What is the situation ahout manifold?

**Theorem** $H_k(S^n-S^r)=R,k=n-r-1$.

> Does this theorem have the corresponding generalization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic words are: [Alexander duality.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality)